# TypeScript Angular Jasmine+Karma test

Tags: angularjs, testing, typescript, jasmine

I spend hours trying to figure this out. I'm trying to test my Angular controller (wrote in typeScript) with tests also in Typescript. I'm stuck on mocking service into my controller. Here is the code :

Controller :

```
export class ProductsController {     
    static $inject = ["ProductService", "$scope"];
    constructor(productsServices: AngularTest.Interfaces.IProductsService, $scope: any) {


            productsServices.getAllProducts().then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<AngularTest.Interfaces.IProducts[]>): any => {
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
            $scope.allProducts = <AngularTest.Interfaces.IProducts[]> response.data

                    $scope.cartItems = [];
                    $scope.modalAlerts = [];

                    $scope.maxItems = 3;
                    $scope.totalItems = $scope.allProducts.length;

                    $scope.itemsOnPage = $scope.allProducts.slice(0, $scope.maxItems);
        });

        $scope.pageChanged = function () {
            $scope.itemsOnPage = $scope.allProducts.slice(($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.maxItems, $scope.currentPage * $scope.maxItems);
        };
    }
}
```

Service :

```
    module AngularTest.Services{
    class ProductServices implements AngularTest.Interfaces.IProductsService{
        httpService: ng.IHttpService

        static $inject = ["$http"];
        constructor($http: ng.IHttpService)
        {
            this.httpService = $http;

        }

        getAllProducts(): ng.IPromise<AngularTest.Interfaces.IProducts[]> {
            return this.httpService.get('/api/Angular');
            };
    }

    factory.$inject = ['$http'];
    function factory($http : ng.IHttpService) {
        return new ProductServices($http);
    }

    angular
        .module('app.AngularTS')
        .factory('ProductService', factory);

}
```

Test :

```
    describe("TestService", () => {

    var mock: ng.IMockStatic;
    var $httpBackend: ng.IHttpBackendService;
    var service; //AngularTest.Interfaces.IProductsService;
    var rootScopeFake;
    var controller;
    var $controller: ng.IControllerService;

    mock = angular.mock;
    beforeEach(mock.module('app.AngularTS'));

    beforeEach(() => inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $injector, $rootScope, _$controller_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        rootScopeFake = $rootScope.$new();
        service = $injector.get('ProductService');    
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    afterEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it("Should Call API", function () {
        controller = $controller('ProductsController', { ProductService: service, $scope: rootScopeFake});

        spyOn(service, "getAllProducts");

        expect($httpBackend.expectGET('/api/Angular').respond([
            { "x": "xx", "xxx": "xxxx", "xxxxx": 5 },
            { "x": "xx", "xxx": "xxxx", "xxxxx": 5.5 },
            { "x": "xx", "xxx": "xxxx", "xxxxx": 6 },
            { "x": "xx", "xxx": "xxxx", "xxxxx": 0 }
        ])).toHaveBeenCalled;

        expect(service.getAllProducts).toHaveBeenCalled();  // this fails why ?
        $httpBackend.flush();

    });
});
```

I don't know why this isn't working i recive.Expected spy getAllProducts to have been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your spy before the method you're spying on is used. Since the method is used in the controller constructor. The spy should be created before initiating your controller.

```
it("Should Call API", function () {        
    spyOn(service, "getAllProducts").and.callFake(function(){
        //return promise
    });

    controller = $controller('ProductsController', { ProductService: service, $scope: rootScopeFake});

    ....
```

Comment: I've done this. Now i'm reciving error : TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'productsServices.getAllProducts().then')
at ProductsController. Any idea ?

Comment: It expects getAllProducts to return a promise. You can achieve this by adding 'and.callFake' to your spy. (I editted my code)   I'm not an expert on TypeScript so I'm not sure how to return a promise with ng.IPromise. I leave that up to you. :-)

Comment: Still reciving error : TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'spyOn(service, "getAllProducts").and.callFake')                                               Method : spyOn(service, "getAllProducts").and.callFake(() => {
            var deffered;
            deffered = q.defer();
            deffered.resolve('xxxx');
            return deffered.promise;
        });

Comment: Which version of jasmine are you using?

Comment: package.json file :  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.8.3",
    "grunt-typescript": "^0.7.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.16",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.2",
    "karma-xml-reporter": "^0.1.4",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.7-8"
  }

Comment: I don't see the jasmine-core in that list, so I asume you're using you're using jasmine 1.*   For v1.* use 'andCallFake'    For v2.* use 'and.callFake'

Comment: you are the men :) i've updated jasmine to 2.3 and test is ok :)